# getInitialProps in Next.js not sending Promise data

Tags: javascript, promise, next.js, dynamic-import

I am using Next.js’s [dynamic routing](https://nextjs.org/docs#dynamic-routing) to display pages and then parts within those pages that are dynamically loaded MDX files.

The url structure is `/product/widget` where *widget* is the name of the page I want to load and reference to all the subparts of the page.

The file structure is like this:

```
src/
  pages/
    product/
      [type].tsx
  parts/
    widget/
      part1.mdx
      part2.mdx
      part3.mdx
      manifest.json
```

Here is the `[type].tsx` file:

```
const Product = ({ renderParts }) => {
  console.log('renderParts on front-end: ')
  console.log(renderParts)

  return (
    <div>plz work</div>
  )
}

Product.getInitialProps = async ({ query }) => {
  // Get target type from URL
  const { type } = query

  // Get parts from manifest
  // This returns an array of files to be loaded 
  // e.g. ['part1.mdx', 'part2.mdx', 'part3.mdx']
  const manifest = await import(`../../parts/${type}/manifest.json`)
  const { parts } = manifest.default

  const renderParts = await Promise.all(
    parts.map(part => (
      import(`../../parts/${type}/${part}.mdx`)
        .then(partModule => partModule.default)
    ))
  ).then(data => data)

  console.log('renderParts in Terminal (server):')
  console.log(renderParts)

  return { renderParts }
}

export default Product
```

When I load the page, this is the results in Terminal:

```
renderParts on front-end: 
[ { [Function: MDXContent] isMDXComponent: true },
  { [Function: MDXContent] isMDXComponent: true },
  { [Function: MDXContent] isMDXComponent: true } ]
```

However, in the Browser's console:

```
renderParts on front-end: 
(3) [null, null, null]
```

I can't figure out why the data is not being passed as props?

Comment: this https://github.com/zeit/next.js/issues/5920 seems to be related